# Is federal tax on sale of home exactly 20% cap gains after 500k exclusion?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, capital-gains-tax, irs

house net income: $2,144,000   (primary residence, sold Aug2020)
basis:  $888,xxx  (bought in 1998)
= net profit of $1,256,xxx
less 500k IRS exclusion  = $756,xxx
long term cap gain rate   20%

so, Fed tax owed =  $151,xxx

Correct?

Comment: No improvements?

Comment: they were negligible

Comment: _IF_ your other taxable income, after deductions, is over about $450k (exact limit depends on filing status) then (all) the capital-gain amount is taxed at 20%. If not, the part of the capital-gain amount that 'fits' in certain lower brackets is taxed at 15%, and if any 'fits' in the ordinary-income 10% or 12% brackets (other income below about $40k single, $50k HOH, $80k MFJ, probably rare for people owning an expensive house) _that_ part is taxed at ZERO. You might want to download the 2019 forms and do a dry run; the 2020 numbers will be _slightly_ different but not much.